# Serializer with foreign key - GET and POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I currently have a model serializer with a foreign key field. I would like the related model to a serialized object rather than just an ID. I know this is possible by creating a serializer for the related model and doing

```
related_field = RelatedFieldSerializer()
```

However, how do I handle the case when creating/updating occurs for the main object? E.g. I want to create an instance of the main object but the related field will get sent as an object (not a pk) and won't refer to the existing foreign key, it will try to create a new object instead.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override the `create` and `update` methods of your serializer.
The `create` method could look like this:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_field = RelatedFieldSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'related_field')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        related_data = validated_data.pop('related_field')
        instance = MyModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
        RelatedModel.objects.create(my_model=instance, **related_data)
        return instance
```

For more information see the documentation about [Writable nested representations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

Comment: I have already overridden create() and update() for writable nested serialization. I don't want to create a new RelatedModel instance, I want to refer to existing one. I want to do something like MyModel.related_field = RelatedModel.objects.get(pk=some_id).

Comment: I want to do the same thing @zubhav...did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to create the existing object, you can do something like this where you leverage `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` as documented [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).

`models.py`

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Model2(models.Model):

    model1= models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    f1 = models.FloatField()
```

Then your `serializers.py` would look like:

```
class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model1 = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=False, queryset=Model1.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = (
            'model1',
            'f1',
        )
```

Then posts can be made against the `pk` value of existing `Model1` values in the database.  Note, you could use other values than the `pk` value if needed.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974094/django-rest-framework-serializer-access-existing-foreign-key).

Comment: Setting `read_only=False` on the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` does not return the serialized nested object. It still returns the id.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `.create()` or `.update()` methods for nested representations.
We can use third party package **drf-writable-nested** provides writable nested model serializer. It allows to create and update models for nested related data.
First need to install

```
pip install drf-writable-nested
```

Example:

```
from drf_writable_nested.serializers import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class ProductSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):

   # FK relation
   category = CategorySerializer(allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'name',
                  'price', 'new']
```

For more details [drf-writable-nested package](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested)

Answer (score 0):

To implement create/update using primary key (pk) of related field and get response as serialized object:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__' # ('id', 'related_field') - for specific fields
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep["related_field"] = RelatedFieldSerializer(instance.related_field).data
        return rep
```

For related field, using ManyToMany relation use:

```
rep["related_field"] = RelatedFieldSerializer(instance.related_field.all(), many=True).data
```

Note : views are created using viewsets.