# Django REST Framework serializer - access existing foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I am using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers) in my app, and I need to create new model instances which contain foreign keys. These refer to existing objects in another table, so I don't want new instances of these foreign objects to be created. Also I cannot access these objects via their primary keys, as that information is not submitted (I need to filter on certain fields which *are* included in the `POST` request).

How do I do this? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014287/serializer-with-foreign-key-get-and-post) question seems to address the same issue, though it's not clear to me that the accepted answer actually solves the problem. Suppose I have two models, `Category` and `Item`, with a `ForeignKey` field in the latter specifying the category:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    format = models.TextField()
    page = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Item(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField()
    title = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True)
    data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The body of the `POST` request consists of a JSON payload, with the category defined as an object specifying the format, page and order fields:

```
POST /api/items
{
  "username" : "test",
  "title" : "foo",
  "category" : {
    "format" : "A",
    "page" : 2,
    "order" : 1
  },
  "data" : [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Then I suppose I might define my `Item` serializer as follows, overriding `create` so that it retrieves the right `Category` instance by filtering on the appropriate fields, and setting it into the returned `Item` instance:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    data = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('username', 'title', 'category', 'data')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        category_dict = validated_data.pop('category')
        item = Item.objects.create(**validated_data)
        format = category_dict.format
        page = category_dict.page
        order = category_dict.order
        item.category = Category.objects.get(format=format, page=page, order=order)
        return item
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: yes it is the right way of doing it. You need to give name as well. So that if a category does not exist with these detail, you can create new category as well. In case if you are sure you are giving the right category which is already available then its the right way of doing it.

Comment: Posted a `pk` answer to the other post just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014287/serializer-with-foreign-key-get-and-post/50616550#50616550

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be like

```
try:
    category = Category.objects.get(format=format, page=page, order=order)
except Category.DoesNotExist:
    # either make it None or create new category, depends on your requirement
    category = None
    # or create new category
except Category.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    category = category.first() # it depends on your requirement
item.category = category
```

Comment: `filter()` doesn't raise an exception. Probably you meant `get()` ??

Answer (score 2):

At least there is one error,you should use `get` to get only one category as you item's category instead of use `filter` to get `queryset`.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    data = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('username', 'title', 'category', 'data')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        category_dict = validated_data.pop('category')
        item = Item.objects.create(**validated_data)
        format = category_dict.format
        page = category_dict.page
        order = category_dict.order
        try:
            item.category = Category.objects.get(format=format, page=page, order=order)
        except  Category.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        except  Category.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            pass
        return item
```